# dbt could not find an incremental strategy macro with the name "get_incremental_insert_sql"

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbt

In DBT Redshift, I have a model with this config:

```
{{config( 
          materialized='incremental',
          incremental_strategy='insert'
        )
}}
```

It runs fine with dbt-core 1.2

```
dbt-core==1.2.4
dbt-extractor==0.4.1
dbt-postgres==1.2.4
dbt-redshift==1.2.0
```

But If I upgrade dbt-core/postgres/redshift to 1.3.0 it breaks with this error:
`dbt could not find an incremental strategy macro with the name "get_incremental_insert_sql"`

Is insert strategy not supported or do I need to alter the config?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `insert` was ever supported; it was probably invalid config being quietly ignored. They refactored this config in 1.3 (see [this issue](https://github.com/dbt-labs/docs.getdbt.com/issues/17610), which added validation.

Your options for Redshift are `append` or `delete+insert`. Since you haven't defined a unique key, I think you probably want `append`.

This should probably be better-documented [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/incremental-models#about-incremental_strategy), but that page doesn't mention PG/Redshift.

Comment: Where can I see Redshift strategies?